# Bootstrap 4 - Custom alert popup box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make certain design with bootstrap for an Alert message card. My idea was to use `<div class="card">` but I don't know if that is the best Idea.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

My design is that the left part of the alert has the background colour #373C47 with an Icon in the middle. And the right part some text with a title.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card depth-5 card-alert-danger">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Icon background color</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <h4 class="card-title m-0">Title</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use columns but that is a bit of a pain in the ass. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using a modal?

Comment: Because it needs to be a popup which displays at the right bottom corner of your screen.

Comment: So, what is the challenge exactly? I'm not getting it.

Comment: I can't find out how I can achieve the background color of the left side to fit to the border. I can't get the layout right.

Comment: what do you mean to `achieve the background color of the left side to fit to the border.`? possible to be more specific? Here is a test. https://www.bootply.com/9bkxMJDrGS# is it sth you need?

Comment: No the background needs to fit to the edges of the card like on the picture. On your example there is a white line around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a **Media Object** in Bootstrap 4.

Here's an example that comes pretty close to your picture using native Bootstrap 4 classes alone (click the "run code snippet" button below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
    body {
        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="media bg-warning">
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle align-self-center m-4" style="font-size: 3rem;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="media-body bg-light p-4">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col">
                           <h5 class="mt-0">Media object heading</h5>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-1 text-right">
                           <a href="#">&times;</a>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: There's no button available to run the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding of the `card-body`, then it will fill the background color to the border.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card depth-5 card-alert-danger">
  <div class="card-body" style="padding:0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="background:#373C47">
        <p style="color:white">Icon background color</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9" style="padding:8px">
        <h4 class="card-title m-0">Title</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you just want the left side to the border, replace `padding:0` with `padding-left:0`.